# Create new company no longer works due to nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources, ruby-on-rails-5

My app has a `Company model` and `User models`, I've been working on the `path/url` structure and have managed to get it working how I wish using nested resources as shown in the code below.

I've used `FriendlyID` to added `company_names` and `usernames` to the models which all works fine.

The path now look how I want they to look:`www.mydomain.com/company_name/username`

**routes.rb**

```
resources :companies, :path => '/', only: [:show] do
    # constraints has been added for usernames that include a '.' 
    resources :users, :path => '/', only: [:show], :constraints => { :id => /.*/ }    
end
```

**PROBLEM**: I still need the ability to add a new company record but it will no longer work. I understand this is due to changing the routes but I don't understand how to remedy this as it keeps viewing

`www.mydomain.com/companies/new` as an unknown user with the `username` 'new'.

I'd be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me a hard with this.

Comment: Is this all of your routes files?

Answer (score 1):

You have set `only: [:show]`, which it means only show method is allowed.

To create a company, need to add `:new` and `:create`.

Something like this `only: [:new, :create, :show]`

**Note:**

Always after adding or changing smth in routes file, make sure to use `rake routes`, Rails 5 supports  `rails routes` also.

You can see available routes!

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply, so quickly too! By adding [:new, :create, :show] to the nested resource I currently have set up I presume it would make the path mydomain.com/company_name/new <br/> if this is the case would I not get an error due to it requiring a company_name of a Company I've not yet created?  <br/> For a :new and :create would I not need to create a total new/separate route/resource in a different format that doesn't require a company name? And if so how would I do that? (hope this makes sense)

Comment: Ignore my comment above, you are spot on thank you! I was being an idiot and adding [:new, :create] to the nested User resource by accident. I've added what you said and it is working great thank you!